# Compiz Window Previews stay for too long after my mouse has long moved away. (Gnome Classic and Xubuntu) Fix?

Tags: compiz

Whenever I use Window Previews Compiz plugin, the previews stay even once I have moved my mouse elsewhere, this happens in Gnome Classic and XFCE too. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Compiz requires good hardware acceleration to work well, which generally means that you'll have to have a relatively recent graphics card. If your graphics card is an old Intel's accelerator, a VIA, or even an old Nvidia 4000/5000, consider either staying away from Compiz or upgrading to more modern hardware.

If you have a decent card, then something is probably misconfigured.